# JClouds: Customizing volumes with Google Compute Engine

Tags: java, google-compute-engine, jclouds

I am not able to find documentation or code examples for the following tasks using JClouds and Google Compute Engine:

- When you are creating an instance, how can you choose SSD instead Standard Disk ?
- How can you customize the size of the root volume ?
- How can you add additional volumes ?

I hope someone can provide me some code samples.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been already answered in the [jclouds mailing list](http://markmail.org/message/qt4sdw43namgm7om), but here is a summary:

Currently there is no way to do that using the ComputeService, but the
GCE provider specific API supports it. The [InstanceApi](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-labs-google/blob/master/google-compute-engine/src/main/java/org/jclouds/googlecomputeengine/features/InstanceApi.java) has the
"create" and "attachDisk" method, that can be used to create instances
with custom disks and attach disks to existing ones.

The former gets a NewInstance object that has a list of AttachDisk
objects. There you cans et the size of the disk and their type. The
same applies to the "attachDisk" method, thich gets an AttachDisk
object. Using those methods you should be able to create instances
with custom disks.

If you have the ComputeServiceContext instance, you can get the
InstanceApi as follows:

```java
GoogleComputeEngineApi gce = context.unwrapApi(GoogleComputeEngineApi.class);
InstanceApi instanceApi = gce.instancesInZone("zone name");
```

Comment: Is there a way to override the default boot-disk-size when creating a new instance? I rather have a larger boot disk than have to manage an additional disk per instance